# Create Many to Many Create/Update in modelSerializer with through table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here are my models

```
   from django.db import models
    class Person(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    class Group(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
    class Membership(models.Model):
        person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
        group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
        fee = models.IntegerField()
```

At Serializer level, i want to save Members and Groups which are M2M related to person through Membership i am trying something like that.
        class GroupMembershipSerializer(ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = Membership
                fields = ('person', 'fee', )

```
    class GroupCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
         memberships = GroupMembershipSerializer(many=True, required=False)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            person_data = validated_data.pop('memberships')
            fee = validated_data.pop('fee')
            # Stuck here ! What should i do here ?
            group = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for person in person_data:
                d=dict(person)
                Membership.objects.create(group=group, person=d['person'])
            return group

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            person_data = validated_data.pop('memberships')
            for item in validated_data:
                if Group._meta.get_field(item):
                    setattr(instance, item, validated_data[item])
            Membership.objects.filter(group=instance).delete()
            for person in person_data:
                d=dict(person)
                Membership.objects.create(group=instance,person=d['person'])
            instance.save()
            return instance

        class Meta:
            model = Group

    class GroupCreateModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = GroupCreateSerializer
        queryset = Group.objects.all()
```

How would it work to save fee in that table too, except that it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive one value for `fee` and want to apply it to all memberships just pass it to `Membership.objects.create()`:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        person_data = validated_data.pop('memberships')
        fee = validated_data.pop('fee')
        group = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for person in person_data:
            d=dict(person)
            Membership.objects.create(group=group, person=d['person'], fee=fee)
        return group
```

Comment: I tried it but validate_data.pop not working I don’t know why ?

Comment: Well, you told everything is working. How does it fail? Any error (and stacktrace)?

Comment: KeyError: 'fee'

Comment: self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Users/mehdiraza/washpro/LaundroSystemAPI/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/Users/mehdiraza/washpro/LaundroSystemAPI/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/Users/mehdiraza/washpro/LaundroSystemAPI/laundroapi/laundromat/serializers.py", line 127, in create
    fee = validated_data.pop('fee')
KeyError: 'fee'

Comment: Can you please add this formatted to your question?

Comment: As you receive a `KeyError` there is no `fee` in `validated_data` - so please also also show us how you execute your creation (view code / form)